# sizeof-operator reverse behavior

Tags: c, sizeof

we know that when we use array it hold address of first element and &array is store whole array address its true when i use in printf but in sizeof operator it is reverse behavior why

i am using code-block with GCC on windows 7

```
 int main(void)
  {
    int c[5];
      printf(" %d  %d  %d  %d\n",c,c+1,&c,&c+1);\\when we add 1 in "c" it add more 4 bytes and when "&c+1" it add 20 byte witch is true

       printf(" %u  %u ",sizeof(c),sizeof(&c));\\But when we print first element size (with "c") it give 20 byte and when print (With "&c") whole arry size it give 4 byte


         return 0;
            }
```

\i cant understand why please explain

Comment: Because the things that *"we know [...]"* are not accurate. You have to re-read what exactly `arr` and `&arr` are

Comment: OT: Seems strange to print the same stuff in the loop. Did you intend to use `i` in the `printf` statement?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(&arr)` is wrong and makes no sense. It resembles the right thing so it's easy to get confused

Comment: You're using the wrong format specifier for `sizeof`, so the behavior is undefined.  A `sizeof` expression has type `size_t`, not `int`.  Your compiler should have warned about this.  You should consider all of the addresses that you printed to be incorrect.

Comment: @TomKarzes compiler ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: @ManpreetSidhu It could be that the sizes happen to be compatible on your platform, in which case the compiler wouldn't recognize the mistake.  Are you using a 32-bit machine?  I would expect a warning on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: @TomKarzes: "*the compiler wouldn't recognize the mistake*" no, as it's not just the size, that might be wrong, but the signedness as well, which *is* wrong. `d` expects a `signed` integer, but `size_t`  is unsigned and so requires *at least* a `u` conversion specifier.

Comment: @alk `gcc` doesn't warn when an `unsigned int` is passed to `%d` or a `signed int` is passed to `%u`.

Comment: @TomKarzes "*doesn't warn*" may be. But it should. As using the wrong length-modifier and/or conversion-specifier might invoke UB.

Comment: @alk It warns if there's a size mismatch (after argument promotion), but does not warn for signed vs. unsigned mismatch.  I'm not sure it considers a sign mismatch to be an error, even though it results in a different interpretation of values whose high-order bit is 1.

Comment: @alk Oh, it looks like there's a separate `gcc` warning option for this: `-Wformat-signedness`. When enabled, it will give the signed vs. unsigned warnings that you want. But note that `-Wall` does not enable this warning.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need to know here is, `&array` is still a pointer, just the type differs.

For an array like `int arr[]={4,3,2,1,0}`

- Most cases, `arr` is same as `&arr[0]`, i.e., `int *`, but with `sizeof` operator, it behaves differently *(see note below)*. When passed to `sizeof` operator, it gives you the size of the whole array, i.e., `sizeof(int [4])` in this case.
- `&arr` is of type `int (*)[4]`, and it's a pointer.

So, to get the number of elements in the array, you should do something like

```
printf ("Number of elements = %zu", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
            / *(size of the entire array / size of one element in the array) */
```

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> **Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator,** the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

That said,

- `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, you should use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.
- to print a pointer to an object, you must use `%p` format specifier and cast the corresponding argument to `void *`.

Comment: printf("%zu  %zu",sizeof(arr),sizeof(&arr)); === output is "zu  zu"

Comment: @ManpreetSidhu Which environment / compiler?

Comment: Number of elements = zu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196690/discussion-between-manpreet-sidhu-and-sourav-ghosh).

Answer (score 4):

First off, if you want to print the result of `sizeof`, the correct format is `%zu`. `sizeof` gives you a `size_t`, not an `int`. To print a pointer, use `%p` and cast the argument to `(void *)`.

Second, to get the number of elements in an array, it's `sizeof arr /  sizeof arr[0]` (size of the whole array divided by the size of a single element, which could also be written `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr`).

That said, the thing you're asking about has nothing to do with arrays, really. For example, if you do

```
char c;
```

then `sizeof &c` will be 4 (on a 32-bit platform), but `&c + 1` will give you a memory address that's 1 byte higher than `&c`, not 4 bytes.

This is because pointer arithmetic is done in units of the pointed-to type (not the type of the pointer itself). That is, you need to compare `ptr + 1` and `sizeof *ptr` (or `&var + 1` and `sizeof var`).

In your code, three of the four expressions are straightforward:

- `sizeof &arr` is 4 because the type of `&arr` is "pointer to array of 5 ints" and you are on a 32-bit platform, so pointers are 4 bytes.
- `sizeof arr` is 20 because the type of `arr` is "array of 5 ints" and `int` is 4 bytes big on your platform, so the array takes 5 * 4 = 20 bytes.
- `&arr + 1` gives you the memory address one past `arr`. It's like asking "if `arr` were an element of an array, where would the next element start?". Since `arr` is 20 bytes big, the memory address one past `arr` is 20 bytes higher.

That leaves the odd one:

- `arr + 1` compiles because `arr` decays to a pointer here. That is, because the array is not the operand of `sizeof` or `&`, it evaluates to a pointer to its first element, like `&arr[0]`. And in `&arr[0] + 1` the pointed-to type is `int`, so adding `1` means stepping to the next `int` in memory, which is 4 bytes away.

Comment: excellent explanation but my confusion is not gone 
# include<stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
     int c[5];
     printf(" %d  %d  %d  %d\n",c,c+1,&c,&c+1);\\when we add 1 in "c" it add more 4 bytes and when "&c+1" it add 20 byte witch is true

     printf(" %u  %u ",sizeof(c),sizeof(&c));\\But when we print first element size (with "c") it give 20 byte and when print (With "&c") whole arry size it give 4 byte
\\i cant understand why

     return 0;
   }